# Unable to update CharField - Django

Tags: python, django, forms, edit

First of all I'm glad to be here, I read you lately and i found useful answers here.
This is my first post so please be kind with me, I'm a newbie in programming.

So, I'm writing my 1st web application in Django - a todo app and I don't know how to write the function that does this this. I found something in Django docs and in other related discussions but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
#models.py

class Task(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
initialized_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
due_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.task

#views.py
def edit_task(request, id):
if request.method == 'POST':
    task_to_edit = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
    form = TaskForm(request.POST, instance=task_to_edit)
    form.save()
    if form.is_valid():
        task_to_edit = form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    form = TaskForm()
return render(request, 'todo/edit_task.html', {'form': form})

#urls.py
url(r'^edit_task/(?P<task_id>\w+)/$', 'todo.views.edit_task')

#edit_task.html
{% block content %}
<form action="/edit_task/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

When I submit the updated form I get this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    hxxp://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_task/
```

Using the URLconf defined in jbz.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^admin/
^$ [name='index']
^(?P<task_id>\d+)/$
^(?P<task_id>\d+)/$
^add-task/$
^delete-task/(?P<task_id>\w+)/$
^edit_task/(?P<id>\w+)/$
^done/(?P<task_id>\d*)/$
```

The current URL, `edit_task/`, didn't match any of these.

and the root urls.py looks like:

```
url(r'', include('todo.urls'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#edit_task.html
{% block content %}
<form action="/edit_task/{{task.id}}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Notice how I added `{{task.id}}` expression in `<form action="/edit_task/{{task.id}}" method="post">`

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Substitute `{{task.id}}` to whatever variable accomplishes this in your template.

The reason why you get the error is because `edit_task/` is not getting the other part, `task_id` to match the regular expression:

```
url(r'^edit_task/(?P<task_id>\w+)/$', 'todo.views.edit_task')
```

**UPDATE:** Also your `edit_task` view has potential errors as well>

```
def edit_task(request, id):
    task_to_edit = Task.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST, instance=task_to_edit)
        form.save()
        if form.is_valid():
            task_to_edit = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    form = TaskForm(instance=task_to_edit)
# you don't pass any task variable to the view so the form view
# won't know which task to edit, you'll have to handle that
return render(request, 'todo/edit_task.html', {'form': form, 'task':task_to_edit})
```

**Note:** I corrected the code in the view a little. Now the `task_to_edit` is passed also to the Form to fill the fields when the view is requested via `GET`. Notice that in order to access to this view, the url in the browser should look like this `http://www.example.com/edit_task/2`

If other wise you try to access `http://www.example.com/edit_task` without passing the id you'll get **Error 404**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks good, but you should not hardcode the action url in the template, use {% url %} tag instead.

Comment: Good point, I just tried to correct his code, not improve it :) BTW hardcoded URL have given me hard times in the past :D

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for your replies. I could edit the task before adding that "task.id" but could not save it. Now even if I added task.id I can't save and I get the same error, but maybe I didn't understand right what did you mean by whatever variable, please could you be more specific? :)

Comment: @jabez I improved the answer a little more.

Comment: @PauloBu Sorry, I was gone. If I replace task_id with id I get:  TypeError at /edit_task/4/

edit_task() got an unexpected keyword argument 'task_id'

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_task/4/
Django Version:  1.5.1
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

edit_task() got an unexpected keyword argument 'task_id'  and if i put task_id back with your new code I have:  ocal variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Request Method:  GET
Exception Type:  UnboundLocalError
 

local variable 'form' referenced before assignment    It's driving me crazy :(

Comment: I just don't understand the status of your code anymore, could you update it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think your pattern for edit task expects an id - task name. Try changing your URL pattern:

```
'^edit_task/(?P<task_id>\w+)/$'
```

to

```
'^edit_task/$'
```

or providing the task id that you want to edit.

Comment: This may work but since `edit_task` should be an action over an object, I think the view should need the objects id. That's why I suggested all the way around.

Comment: Maybe you need a special error handler for when the task isn't defined ;-)

Comment: one easy fix is to have both the url targets in the urlpatterns.

Comment: First I'm trying to edit existing task and after that I'll deal further issues... :(

Answer (score 0):

Just add name space to your url and according update your template.

```
#urls.py
url(r'^edit_task/(?P<task_id>\w+)/$', 'todo.views.edit_task', name= "edit_task")

#edit_task.html
{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'edit_task' task_id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i get the following error: Exception Type:  NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:  

Reverse for 'edit_task' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: which Django version you are using ?

Comment: Have you update the urls.py as mentioned, because if the URL you’re reversing doesn’t exist, you’ll get an NoReverseMatch exception raised, which will cause your site to display an error page.